# How to turn-off showing child items for selected Main Menu items in Umbraco CMS?

Tags: umbraco

In order to explain my issue easier, please first see this photo

[image]

On my template I have already configured Top navigation but problem is that I am trying to make new menu Item which will be called 'News' and thing is that I don't want that every out of 99 news items I will publish (in next two months), to be autmatically available as sumbenu child item under 'News'.

As I noticed, most of the configuration is under 'umbTopNavigation.xslt'

```
]> 
 xmlns:msxml="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
 xmlns:umbraco.library="urn:umbraco.library"
 exclude-result-prefixes="msxml umbraco.library">
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />

<xsl:param name="currentPage"/>

<!-- Input the documenttype you want here -->
<xsl:variable name="level" select="1"/>

<xsl:template match="/">

    <ul id="topNavigation">
   <li class="home">
     <xsl:if test="$currentPage/@id = $currentPage/ancestor-or-self::* [@level=$level]/@id">
         <xsl:attribute name="class">home current</xsl:attribute>
     </xsl:if>
     <a href="/">Home</a>
   </li>
  <xsl:for-each select="$currentPage/ancestor-or-self::* [@level=$level]/* [@isDoc and string(umbracoNaviHide) != '1']">   <li>
 <xsl:if test="@id = $currentPage/@id">
    <xsl:attribute name="class">current</xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:if>
<a class="navigation" href="{umbraco.library:NiceUrl(@id)}">
  <span><xsl:value-of select="@nodeName"/></span>
</a>   </li>
  </xsl:for-each> </ul>

</xsl:template>
```

but I can't figure out what exactly I need to change?
Any help is appreciated and many thanks in advance! 
MC2012
First macro

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE xsl:stylesheet [ <!ENTITY nbsp "&#x00A0;"> ]>
<xsl:stylesheet 
  version="1.0" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
  xmlns:msxml="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" 
  xmlns:umbraco.library="urn:umbraco.library"
  exclude-result-prefixes="msxml umbraco.library">

<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

<xsl:param name="currentPage"/>

<xsl:template match="/">

  <xsl:variable name="items" select="$currentPage/ancestor-or-self::* [@isDoc and @level = 2]/* [@isDoc and string(umbracoNaviHide) != '1']"/>

<!-- The fun starts here -->

<xsl:if test="count($items) &gt; 0">
<ul>
<xsl:for-each select="$items">
  <li>
    <a href="{umbraco.library:NiceUrl(@id)}">
      <xsl:value-of select="@nodeName"/>
    </a>
  </li>
</xsl:for-each>
</ul>
    </xsl:if>

</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Second Macro

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet
    version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:umbraco.library="urn:umbraco.library"
    exclude-result-prefixes="umbraco.library"
>

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />

    <xsl:param name="currentPage" />

    <!-- Specify level of the top node for a language (usually 1) -->
    <xsl:variable name="level" select="1" />

    <!-- Grab the top node -->
    <xsl:variable name="siteRoot" select="$currentPage/ancestor-or-self::*[@level = $level]" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <ul class="menu">
            <!-- Create the Home link -->
            <li>
                <xsl:if test="$currentPage/@id = $siteRoot/@id">
                    <xsl:attribute name="class">sel</xsl:attribute>
                </xsl:if>
                <a href="{umbraco.library:NiceUrl($siteRoot/@id)}">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$siteRoot/@nodeName" />
                </a>
            </li>
            <!-- Process all children of $siteRoot (if any) -->
            <xsl:apply-templates select="$siteRoot/*[@isDoc][not(umbracoNaviHide = 1)]" />
        </ul>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Generic template for all nav links -->
    <xsl:template match="*[@isDoc]">
        <li>
            <xsl:if test="@id = $currentPage/@id">
                <xsl:attribute name="class">sel</xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:if>
            <a href="{umbraco.library:NiceUrl(@id)}">
                <xsl:value-of select="@nodeName" />
            </a>
            <!-- Render sub menu if necessary -->
            <xsl:call-template name="submenu" />
        </li>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Template for Inactive links -->
    <xsl:template match="*[@isDoc][umbracoNaviInactive = 1]">
        <li>
            <xsl:if test="@id = $currentPage/@id">
                <xsl:attribute name="class">sel</xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:if>
            <span>
                <xsl:value-of select="@nodeName" />
            </span>
            <!-- Submenu? -->
            <xsl:call-template name="submenu" />
        </li>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Template checking for, and processing any submenu -->
    <xsl:template name="submenu">
        <xsl:variable name="subPages" select="*[@isDoc][not(umbracoNaviHide = 1)]" />
        <xsl:if test="$subPages">
            <ul>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="$subPages" />
            </ul>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Are you sure you have the correct macro listed here? It looks like the code above would only support a single level navigation as opposed to multi level navgiation.

Comment: Hello Carl, it looks like I found two more Macros on my template.

Comment: I have edited my first question and at the bottom of the question you will find code for first and second macro. Thank you, MC2012

Answer (score 0):

Ok - you have two options. A quick hack or a full solution.

The quick hack is to update the second macro where the subnav is called and exclude the subnav being called where it's the news page (and you can include other pages in here too)

In this example I've used node ID 1107 to be the ID of your news page, but you will need to update this with your actual news page ID.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet
    version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:umbraco.library="urn:umbraco.library"
    exclude-result-prefixes="umbraco.library"
>

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />

    <xsl:param name="currentPage" />

    <!-- Specify level of the top node for a language (usually 1) -->
    <xsl:variable name="level" select="1" />

    <!-- Grab the top node -->
    <xsl:variable name="siteRoot" select="$currentPage/ancestor-or-self::*[@level = $level]" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <ul class="menu">
            <!-- Create the Home link -->
            <li>
                <xsl:if test="$currentPage/@id = $siteRoot/@id">
                    <xsl:attribute name="class">sel</xsl:attribute>
                </xsl:if>
                <a href="{umbraco.library:NiceUrl($siteRoot/@id)}">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$siteRoot/@nodeName" />
                </a>
            </li>
            <!-- Process all children of $siteRoot (if any) -->
            <xsl:apply-templates select="$siteRoot/*[@isDoc][not(umbracoNaviHide = 1)]" />
        </ul>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Generic template for all nav links -->
    <xsl:template match="*[@isDoc]">
        <li>
            <xsl:if test="@id = $currentPage/@id">
                <xsl:attribute name="class">sel</xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:if>
            <a href="{umbraco.library:NiceUrl(@id)}">
                <xsl:value-of select="@nodeName" />
            </a>
            <!-- Render sub menu if necessary excluding the news pages -->
            <xsl:if test="not(@id=1107)">
                <xsl:call-template name="submenu" />
            </xsl:if>
        </li>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Template for Inactive links -->
    <xsl:template match="*[@isDoc][umbracoNaviInactive = 1]">
        <li>
            <xsl:if test="@id = $currentPage/@id">
                <xsl:attribute name="class">sel</xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:if>
            <span>
                <xsl:value-of select="@nodeName" />
            </span>
            <!-- Submenu? -->
            <xsl:call-template name="submenu" />
        </li>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Template checking for, and processing any submenu -->
    <xsl:template name="submenu">
        <xsl:variable name="subPages" select="*[@isDoc][not(umbracoNaviHide = 1)]" />
        <xsl:if test="$subPages">
            <ul>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="$subPages" />
            </ul>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The proper way to do it would be to add a property to your document type to include a property to say do not list children or similar, and then test for that in the XSLT, but that's a much more involved fix, and for that I suggest you read up a bit more on how XSLTs work. Let me know if you want to go down that route and there are plenty of resources I can direct you to

thanks,

Comment: If this answer is helpful I'd appreciate you marking this as an answer. If not - no worries